# i can't run very simple example of tabs on android

Tags: android, eclipse

hi every one i have this problem. i actually need to add two tabs on an android aplication and i am reading the how to do it in developer.android.com but i can't run the program

here is mi code:

```
package com.example.example;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

         actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

         ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {


            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };

         // Add 3 tabs, specifying the tab's text and TabListener
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText("Tab " + (i + 1))
                            .setTabListener(tabListener));
        }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and here is the compiling error:

```
02-23 16:09:20.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23928): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 16:09:20.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23928): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.example.example.MainActivity.getActionBar
02-23 16:09:20.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23928):    at com.example.example.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
02-23 16:09:20.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23928):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
02-23 16:09:20.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23928):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1698)
02-23 16:09:20.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23928):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1753)
02-23 16:09:20.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23928):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155)
02-23 16:09:20.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23928):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:999)
02-23 16:09:20.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23928):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
02-23 16:09:20.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23928):    at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
02-23 16:09:20.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23928):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3820)
02-23 16:09:20.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23928):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 16:09:20.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23928):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
02-23 16:09:20.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23928):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:969)
02-23 16:09:20.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23928):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:727)
02-23 16:09:20.164: E/AndroidRuntime(23928):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i think the problem is in the manifest.xml because when i tried to inserte this two lines :

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS)
ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
```

the eclipse show me an error that says "the minium sdk should be 11 and your minium sdk is 8"

then i change it in the manifest.xml, the menssage error disapear but i can't run it on my phone

here is mi android_manifest.mxl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.example.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `support` library to use the `ActionBar` in devices running an SO version lower to API 11.

Take a look at how to [Setup Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html).

To make use of the `ActionBar` you should call:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = geSupportActionBar();
```

To make sure everything is working okay you must `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar`.

Comment: i have the android.support.v4.app i added it but shows an error
"Only a type can be imported android.support.v4.app resolves to a package"

Comment: The support `ActionBar` is inside of v7 library and not v4!

Comment: ok then i have three directories that have three jars 
for import to the project
1.- appcompat
2.- gridlayout
3.- mediarouter

wich one i should import to my project?

Comment: i added the appcompat and its solves a little but i can't call the getSupportActionBar method.